# SQL Query that needs a little bit modification

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
select 
    IF(posty.id IS NULL, 0, 1) as posty,
    IF(strony.id IS NULL, 0, 1) as strony,
    posty.*, strony.*,
    `master`.url
from
(select 'fajne-to-jest' as url)  `master`
left join posty on posty.url = `master`.url
left join strony on strony.url = `master`.url
;
```

Above queries generate the below result:

[image]

And it doesn't work exactly 100% as I'd like it to. Because I want results like

this: [image]
The actual and desired results are different, because in the desired result it eliminates columns with NULL values, and the one url column which apears twice is reduced to one. Below is further visual clarification:

[image]

And the question is: is it possible to make this query?
What should the query look like? How to structure it?

Comment: You're getting all of the columns from both posty and strony. Try getting only the columns you want.

Comment: It is showing twice because you have selected all columns from posty and strony. Use exact column names if you want some specific data.

Comment: Is it possible to... for example, we have 20 columns. We want to get only 19.... so do we really have to type these 19 coulmns? Or maybe there is way to only substract this one columnd we don't want to?

Comment: Yes, list 19 out individually (instead of using *) and don't list the one you want to exclude. Sometimes writing SQL is a bit repetitive. It is almost always better to only include the columns you want in your queries for many reasons (performance, readability, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the NULL value showing up, you can use the following construct:

```
if (isnull(mycolumn) ,'',mycolumn) as mycolumn
```

Regarding duplicated columns:

As a general rule, in a prod environment, you should always list the columns you want to appear in the result, instead of using the * wildcard.  Replace the wildcard with the column listing and you are set.